# Caching the node_modules directory in react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, node-modules, yarnpkg

I'm working on an application where I'd like to cache the contents of the `node_modules` folder on subsequent `yarn install` commands. Everything in the caching logic is working fine, however, I get an error when using the cached directory saying

```
$ react-scripts build

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638

throw err;

^

Error: Cannot find module '../scripts/build'

at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)

at Function.resolve (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:33:19)

at Object.<anonymous> (/local/frontend/node_modules/.bin/react-scripts:31:23)

at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)

at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)

at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)

at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)

at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)

at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)

at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)

error Command failed with exit code 1.

info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Is this because the `react-scripts` binary isn't around on the second build? And if so, does the container that runs this have to have `react-scripts` on it ahead of time?

Comment: What are you building this on, a CI service?

Comment: Also, what's the purpose for caching this? It seems like there's no need to do it locally.

Comment: Yes on a CI service. I'm caching this to speed up the build.

Comment: What CI service are you using?